# I think I found a way to use entangled photons to send messages. What’s wrong with this argument?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

The argument has been made that entangled photons cannot be used to send messages due to the statistical nature of the phenomena.  I think I found a way to do this that is so simple, it’s like a parlor trick.  Here’s the basic idea in a nutshell.  (The whole idea can be found here: http://vixra.org/abs/1911.0278 )

We start by placing an EPR source of entangled photons midway between Alice on the left, and Bob on the right.   The source produces a steady stream of photons directed toward Alice and Bob.

In the center, with the EPR source, we pass the photons directed toward Alice through a vertically aligned polarizing beam splitter (BS).   We expect about half of the photons to be vertically polarized, and half to be horizontally polarized.  For simplicity, let us discard the latter horizontally polarized photons.

On the left, Alice receives only vertically polarized photons.  She passes these photons through yet another vertically aligned polarizing beam splitter (BS).  She has two photon counters, one to count the vertically polarized photons, and one to count the horizontally polarized photons.  Naturally, she expects to see all of her photons vertically polarized.

Alice will indeed see almost all of her photons vertically polarized, provided that Bob does not touch his partner photons.  And indeed, Bob takes great care to ensure his partner photons to do touch anything, at least until Alice has had a chance to measure her photons.

Bob is an interesting guy.  Whenever he gets hungry for pizza, he starts passing all the photons he receives from the EPR source through a polarizing beam splitter aligned at a 45-degree angle.  Furthermore, he places his BS at a distance guaranteed to ensure that his photons get measured just before Alice’s partner photons arrive at her BS.

Essentially, Bob has manipulated Alice’s photons in such a way that Alice will now see her photons split 50-50 between her two detectors.  When Alice’s sees a statistically significant number of photons split like this, she knows it is time for pizza with Bob.

In theory, Alice and Bob could be widely separated in space, say 20 light minutes apart.  According to QM, Alice will know instantaneously when Bob wants pizza, which of course is the reason Bob went through all the trouble in the first place.  Alice on the other hand is very concerned about the implications for theoretical physics:  what would it mean if we have experimentally demonstrated action at a distance that is super-luminal?  Folks go through a lot of trouble to ensure their theories are Lorentz covariant.

My questions are: 
1) what's wrong with my logic?
2) Is this a problem for QM or not?  Sometimes I wonder if theoretical physists really believe the voodoo-like aspects of QM, and if they just nod their heads and go back to their ever effective calculations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because anything referencing vixra is *ipso facto* not serious.

Comment: I voted to close because anything that calls for a calculation about measurements on an entangled state but fails to *specify* that state is *ipso facto* not serious.

Comment: Please and thank you.  The only reason I took the time to write the paper and post it on vixra was because a post-doc at Oxford suggested it when he would find no problem with the ideas.  I've already submitted a withdrawl form at vixra, wish I had never heard of it, and am frankly mortified.  Kill this please.

Answer (score 1):

When Alice's photons pass through the first polarizing beam splitter (thereby becoming vertically polarized), that constitutes a measurement, and the results of Bob's manipulations become completely determined.

Comment: Note that Bob is measuring at a 45 degree angle, and the photons he is measuring are either Vert or Horz polarized.   He should see a 50-50 split if he were to measure polarization at this angle.  We could alternatively let Bob's photons hit a wall, at which point, Alice's photons would be put in an undetermined state, yielding again a 50-50 split at her detectors.  My question back to you is, will Alice see a change at her detectors?  Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: @Bryce.Corbin The point is, Alice's photons become deterministic once they go through the beam splitter. The beam splitter is a measuring device, her detectors are irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry to be so dense, but are you saying that when Bob changes the state of his partner photon, it has no affect on the probability distribution at Alice's detectors?

Comment: @Bryce.Corbin yes. Alice sees only vertically polarized photons regardless of what Bob does.

Answer (score 0):

Why Bob's measurement should affect Alice's ones? Bob receives twice the photons, with both polarizations, as he has not discarded any polarization. Plus Bob does not even measure Vertical or Horizontal, only diagonal angles compatible with the vertical polarization that Alice sees.